# Additional body tag in ckeditor

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor , but if i am  trying to enter data from an iphone,its  insert an additional body tag to the data base,but its work fine in computers.How can i avoid this extra body tag .

I am using editor.getData() for taking data  from ckeditor.

Any one please help me

Comment: Dirty but fast solution is to check on server-side if extra tag exists.

Comment: No there is no extra tags, its work fine in computers

Comment: You've told that when iphone is used extra body tag is used. So, my solution was to check data that needs to be inserted in db has extra body tag or not and if has remove it on server-side